# is there a(n) easy way to test js code on different mobile OS

Tags: testing, frontend, compatibility

Recently I write html/js code about SVG, I want to test these codes on different mobileOS (iOS8+, Android4.x+), but I have no all of these hardware and OS.
Is there a good way to test?

Comment: You can download Mobile Emulator. Opera has a [mobile Emulator](https://www.opera.com/nl/developer/mobile-emulator)

Answer (score 0):

**for iOS:**

Donwload XCode -- preference -- download the OS you want -- select a phone and OS -- run a demo -- shift+command+h -- open the safari and run your page

**for Android:**

Download Genymotion, for more just click [here](https://docs.genymotion.com/pdf/PDF_User_Guide/Genymotion-2.8.1-User-Guide.pdf)